# Communicating between two NICs through a managed switch without using the main router attached to the switch

Tags: networking, lan

So the switch(CISCO WS-C3750-48TS-S) is connected to the ISP using the SFP port, they configured the switch when they gave us the connection. We just have to plugin the client's cable into the ethernet ports of the switch and they get their Lan parameters, then they are given a username and password which they put in the VPN dialer and access the internet. Is it possible to configure two PCs connected to two of the ports of the switch but without involving the ISP's router/DHCP server? I tried doing this by giving both PCs static IPs which were way different than the IPs given by the ISP's router.

For PC 1 I set the parameters to : IP address: 192.168.0.20 ,Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

For PC 2 I set the parameters to : IP address: 192.168.0.21 ,Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

The ISP's router gives parameters like : IP address: 172.31.xxx.x ,Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

But I still can't ping one pc from the other, if I connect both PCs on an 8 port switch then they work fine, even when that switch is connected to a simple router. So is this possible, what am I doing wrong. Thanks.

here is an image giving a rough idea of the whole network:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFaPS.png

Comment: WHty do you think it's going to work? You have a managed switch. It is managed by the ISP. If you want to configure your own network you need to attach a router to the switch and go from there.

Comment: So would every client have to go through the router and then to the isp or i could just attach a router's lan port to one of the ports of the switch

Comment: You would attach the router's **WAN** port to the switch.

Comment: And all the clients would go in the lan of the router? Or stay in the switch?

Comment: The PCs will communicate via the router. If they need access outside the LAN that will be via the switch ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: Are you suggesting that the ISP has preconfigured the switch to block LAN ports from each other? What OP does _should_ work with any switch unless something was deliberately done to prevent it, and that's usually only done to separate multiple customers or such.

Comment: @zanrpg Are you able to configure the Switch at all? If not ask your ISP if they can configure two ports of the Switch in a different Vlan that does not reach the Router. You should let the ISP choose one IP you'll then use as gateway should you still want to reach the internet.

Comment: @grawity It's not clear, but it may be that the ISP has configured the switch with multiple VLANs, given the OP seems to have separate logins on different ports with separate VPNs

Comment: @grawity the switch is ours, it's at our office, we can configure it as we want but I have zero knowledge on how to configure it and i a bit afraid in ruining the network. I don't think that the isp has an intention to block ports from each other, they just providing connectivity, some dealers are even using unmanaged switches where we've used this managed switch, and their network also works fine, and I don't think that there are vlans for separate VPNs cause we have used 8 port switches on most of the ports of this switch because we have like 200 end users right now

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to make a simple diagnostic system that will notify me whenever a cable breaks or there is a problem with any of the switch.
here is poorly drawn picture of the network: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFaPS.png
I have already tested the microcontroller, all i want is to ping Mcontroller 3 and 1 using Mcontroller 2.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, but suddenly there's a whole lot more going on than just the one switch... Do you have access to the switch's configuration?

Comment: @grawity I have no idea on how can I check it's configuration, if you can give me some info then I would be happy to try it